# Meaning of "attract to date" in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

While I was reading an article related to renewable energy, I found this and could not see the meaning of the part of the sentence.

The good news is that a decade of subsidy-driven growth has brought with it falling costs. Renewables are still on the pricey side in many places, but they are getting less so; in some places wind, in particular, is reasonably competitive. This suggests that their growth might soon need a lot less subsidy than **it has attracted to date**.

Comment: "...than it has attracted *up to the present time*.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase

> to date

means from the beginning (or some time in the past) until now, "until today".

Your excerpt is saying that before there has been subsidies for renewable energy to encourage growth (*attract*), but since renewable energy sales seem to be be self sustaining, there may no longer be as many subsidies in the future (*to date*).

Comment: The question asks about the meaning of “attract to date”, not just "to date".

Comment: @user3169 "attract to date" is not a discrete constituent, and therefore has no discrete meaning: *to date* is a temporal PP modifying the clause *it has attracted [x much subsidy]*.